# QT и UML диаграммы

Tags: qt

У меня есть проект написанный в QT и мне нужно построить по нему UML диаграмму классов. Подскажите, есть ли в qt встроенный инструмент для построение uml диаграмм по текущему проекту или без помощи сторонних программ типо doxygen не обойти?

Comment: встроенного нет, это понятно по хелпу, в котором наследование описывается словами, без графики